# How can I stop GCP instance groups from terminating

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP load balancer pointing to an instance group. Right now I don't need autoscaling yet so it's turned off. I am at a stage of configuring the server. Periodically it seems the server "crashes" and GCP shuts it down and launches a new instance, causing me to lose all work. Its a pain to create images, update the instance template. I'd much rather it just doesn't crash on me periodically and act like a "normal" instance where the state is saved.

Comment: Use an unmanaged instance group instead of managed instance group. Then replace the backend in your load balancer.

Comment: You can disable health check in instance group.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might be currently using a managed instance group.

At least in this stage of your project, you are quickly iterating on state (at the very least, configuration) on a per-instance basis, you should probably be using an unmanaged instance group rather than a managed instance group.  Here is a reference about the [instance group types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).

A managed instance group effectively manages "cattle" -- they're all pretty much identical, and if one dies, its easy to replace it, there's not nothing special about the individuals -- they all follow templates and images and one is as good as the other.

On the other hand, an unmanaged instance group is more like "pets" -- you have customized each instance, and you're just using the instance group to, for example, manage a loadbalancer across the fleet of machines yourself.

Based on your question, you're currently doing some custom config as you get your system operational, so you're probably more in the later category -- thus, using an unmanaged group would let you test with the loadbalancer and verify things are working.

When you are ready for a production deployment and have the images complete, then a managed instance group can give you auto scaling, healing, and other features that would be desirable.